# Redirect all pages to one page on same domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/path/to/file.php$
RewriteRule $ /path/to/file.php [R=302,L]
```

and the purpose to is redirect a specific IP who visits any page to one page in particular  /path/to/file.php

This is working for URLs which have spaces in them.  But it is not working for URLs which contain %20 instead of spaces, and URLs which have no spaces.  Where have I gone wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change this line:

```
RewriteRule $ /path/to/file.php [R=302,L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/file.php [R=302,L]
```

you will be good to go. Make sure you clear your browser cache when you test redirects.